# is there any way to customize ignite built-in cleaning TTL functions

Tags: ignite

I see that Ignite currently supports the TTL feature to remove unusual keys. Is there any way to customize this TTL feature?
In my case, I have BinaryObjects in IgniteCache, key -> BinaryObject, and those BinaryObjects contain several values, one of them is a timestamp. Could I customize Ignite's built-in cleaning TTL functions somehow so that Ignite can check the timestamp value and decide to remove or keep a key?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can implement your own expiry policy if you like. You just need to create a class that implements [`ExpiryPolicy`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0/javax/cache/expiry/ExpiryPolicy.html). And each row can have a different policy.

However, you'll note that the API does not give access to the record, so you can't have it automatically set the policy based on a column.